# How does random forest determine the possible split values to assess?

Tags: random-forest, cart

I understand the basics of how decision trees / random forests are built, but one thing I still don't have a good answer for is how the putative split values are identified. So suppose we have mtry = 5, and at a given split we randomly select 5 variables to try. Does the algorithm try every possible split for each of these variables? I.e., if there are 100 unique split values for each variable, it assesses 5*100 = 500 different split values, calculating node impurity or variance for each one? And does this vary between CART and random forest?

Comment: Yes, this is done like this. In gradient boosting, dense features are sometimes internally binned to reduce the number of unique values. For CART and random forests, this is not yet the standard, I'd say.